# How can I add Bootstrap 5 animation to a web page

Tags: css, css-animations, bootstrap-5

I want to add animations like [This one](https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/jOWMGON) to a background of this page down below, but i don't know how to do that using bootstrap 5, the image i provided up here, i want it to be the background of my html page, How can i do this please?

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
```

My Templates:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-light bg-body shadow-lg">
        <div class="row">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light bg-body shadow-sm">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: dodgerblue; font-size: 20px;">DB</a>
                        <div class="navbar-nav">
                            <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">About</a>
                            <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Contact</a>
                            <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Pricing</a>
                            <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Disabled</a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            <div class="col">
                <div class="container p-5">
                    <h1>Landing Page</h1>
                    <br>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur recusandae 
                    accusamus enim dolorum sequi saepe unde minima</h4>
                    <br>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg bg-body text-dark" href="">Get Started</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="p-5">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Sign In</h2>
                <br>
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="text-primary text-dark font-weight-bold">Enter School Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="School Name">
                    </div>
  
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="text-primary text-dark font-weight-bold">Enter School Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How can we figure out what kind of animation you want to get, from a photo and without seeing the css?

Comment: actually I downloaded the photo from the internet, this is my first time, so i don't know how to do that using css, as a backend developer.

Comment: Friend, it depends as already said on the animation you want to make. There are thousands that can be done. Put it in the background of your container if that's enough for you. For the animations watch some tutorials on YouTube or see on this site https://freefrontend.com/css-animated-backgrounds/

Comment: What if I want [this one](https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/jOWMGON) as a background sir. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the code from the [fiddle](https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/jOWMGON) (the *compiled* css) and use `bubbles` as the class for your required container. In this case, I used a `fixed` div as the background of page.

(Wait for it...)

```css
body {
  background: #1a1e23;
  margin: 0;
}

.bubbles {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--bubble-left-offset);
  bottom: -75%;
  display: block;
  width: var(--bubble-radius);
  height: var(--bubble-radius);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: float-up var(--bubble-float-duration) var(--bubble-float-delay) ease-in infinite;
}

.bubble::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(136, 246, 251, 0.3);
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: var(--bubble-sway-type) var(--bubble-sway-duration) var(--bubble-sway-delay) ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

.bubble:nth-child(0) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 70vw;
  --bubble-radius: 2vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(1) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 92vw;
  --bubble-radius: 8vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(2) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 60vw;
  --bubble-radius: 2vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(3) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 93vw;
  --bubble-radius: 8vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(4) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 77vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(5) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 36vw;
  --bubble-radius: 8vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(6) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 33vw;
  --bubble-radius: 6vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(7) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 84vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 7s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(8) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 3vw;
  --bubble-radius: 2vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(9) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 89vw;
  --bubble-radius: 1vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(10) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 87vw;
  --bubble-radius: 9vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(11) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 98vw;
  --bubble-radius: 7vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(12) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 80vw;
  --bubble-radius: 10vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 7s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(13) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 97vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(14) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 28vw;
  --bubble-radius: 1vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(15) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 64vw;
  --bubble-radius: 10vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(16) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 3vw;
  --bubble-radius: 6vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(17) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 14vw;
  --bubble-radius: 6vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(18) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 41vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(19) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 31vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(20) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 49vw;
  --bubble-radius: 7vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 7s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(21) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 89vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(22) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 47vw;
  --bubble-radius: 8vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(23) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 93vw;
  --bubble-radius: 7vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(24) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 72vw;
  --bubble-radius: 5vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(25) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 68vw;
  --bubble-radius: 4vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(26) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 15vw;
  --bubble-radius: 5vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(27) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 20vw;
  --bubble-radius: 4vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(28) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 51vw;
  --bubble-radius: 8vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(29) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 31vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(30) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 45vw;
  --bubble-radius: 5vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(31) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 9vw;
  --bubble-radius: 7vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(32) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 62vw;
  --bubble-radius: 5vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(33) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 8vw;
  --bubble-radius: 4vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(34) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 76vw;
  --bubble-radius: 1vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(35) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 22vw;
  --bubble-radius: 10vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(36) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 82vw;
  --bubble-radius: 7vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(37) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 30vw;
  --bubble-radius: 10vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(38) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 96vw;
  --bubble-radius: 8vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(39) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 13vw;
  --bubble-radius: 5vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 8s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(40) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 8vw;
  --bubble-radius: 7vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(41) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 66vw;
  --bubble-radius: 1vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 9s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(42) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 11vw;
  --bubble-radius: 4vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 10s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(43) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 57vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(44) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 53vw;
  --bubble-radius: 5vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

.bubble:nth-child(45) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 18vw;
  --bubble-radius: 1vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 7s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(46) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 72vw;
  --bubble-radius: 2vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 7s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 4s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(47) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 80vw;
  --bubble-radius: 3vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 2s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(48) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 83vw;
  --bubble-radius: 8vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 12s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 1s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(49) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 16vw;
  --bubble-radius: 10vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 11s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 5s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 0s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-left-to-right;
}

.bubble:nth-child(50) {
  --bubble-left-offset: 0vw;
  --bubble-radius: 7vw;
  --bubble-float-duration: 7s;
  --bubble-sway-duration: 6s;
  --bubble-float-delay: 3s;
  --bubble-sway-delay: 4s;
  --bubble-sway-type: sway-right-to-left;
}

@keyframes float-up {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-175vh);
  }
}

@keyframes sway-left-to-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes sway-right-to-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid bg-light bg-body shadow-lg">
  <div class="row">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light bg-body shadow-sm">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: dodgerblue; font-size: 20px;">DB</a>
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Contact</a>
          <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="bubbles">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="bubble"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col position-relative">


      <div class="container p-5">
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
        <br>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur recusandae accusamus enim dolorum sequi saepe unde minima</h4>
        <br>
        <a class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg bg-body text-dark" href="">Get Started</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="p-5">
        <h2 class="text-center">Sign In</h2>
        <br>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-primary text-dark font-weight-bold">Enter School Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="School Name">
          </div>

          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-primary text-dark font-weight-bold">Enter School Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
          </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```